# Every surface of sufficiently large genus separates

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, smooth-manifolds, 3-manifolds, surfaces

Let $M^3$ be a smooth closed orientable manifold.
Does there exist a non negative integer $g_0$ such that every closed orientable embedded surface $\Sigma \subset M$ of genus $g \geq g_0$ represents the trivial class in the second homology group $H_2(M; \mathbb{Z})$?

My thoughts: if every surface separates, then we are done. If this is not the case, let $\Sigma$ be one nonseparating surface of genus $g$. Then, attaching small handles to $\Sigma$ would produce nonseparating surfaces of every genus $\geq g$.

(sorry if it is a silly question…)

Comment: I think your argument is fine.  If you can find a surface of genus $g$ that is not nullhomologous, then you can stabilize it to increase the genus to whatever you want without changing the homology class.  It's more interesting to try to *minimize* the genus of a surface representing a given homology class (c.f. the Thurston norm).

Comment: Another more interesting question might be to ask if there are *incompressible* surfaces of arbitrarily large genus that represent non-trivial classes in $H_2$. (Note that your high-genus examples will all be compressible.) I believe this is always true for fibred hyperbolic manifolds $M$ with $b_2(M)>1$, again using the theory of the Thurston norm -- specifically the fact that fibred classes form an open subset of the unit norm ball.

Comment: Even the hypothesis on $b_2$ is not necessary.  Here is one reference: *Knots with infinitely many incompressible Seifert surfaces* by Robin Wilson.  I assume that these remain distinct and incompressible after longitudinal filling.  And if they don't, then I bet there is another family with this extra property.  :)